# Added EU cookie compliance on Drupal 7 not working properly

Tags: drupal-7, jquery-cookie

I have Drupal 7 installation with EU Cookie Compliance module installed. I've enabled the plugin and added permissions, so that the compliance is showing to everyone.

The expected behavior should be:

- user is on the website and the cookie compliance is showing with the `OK` and `read more` buttons.
- then the user clicks the `OK` button and the message is disappearing and a `thank you for accepting...` message is shown
- when the user refreshes the page, he must not see this message again

But what I get is:

- the user is on the website, sees the compliance and clicks `ok` - the message hides
- but when the user goes on another page (or refreshes the current) instead of not showing the message, the plugin is showing it, then hides it (with no user interaction), then shows the `thank you for accepting...` message

I saw the following:

- a cookie with name `cookie-agreed` is set to null
- then if user clicks `ok`, the `cookie-agreed` cookie is updated to `1`
- then a `thank you...` message is shown and after that, the cookie is updated to value of `2`
- but then, after page reload, instead of `2`, the `cookie-agreed` cookie is `null`, then set to `1`, which causes the user to see the cookie compliance message, then the message slides down, then the `thank you...` message is shown again, on every page reload, no matter what user clicks or don't clicks.

The settings in the module are the default ones. I've only changed:
`var status` to `var status_eu_cookie_compliance` so that there are no conflicts for this variable on the website and the `expires` value for the cookie to integer `365` (I've changed the default date in the module's js code). Any ideas where I'm going wrong with this?

The `$.cookie` is set and working.